# Indexing Issues

Tags: r, indexing, plot, dataframe

I've been trying to plot the difference between two sets of information (the residuals).  Both sets of data have similar (yet different) characteristics, and both data sets go from 0 to the same X value.  The only inconsistency is that they are indexed differently, so while the first graph reaches X in A steps, the second reaches X in B steps.  Thus, I cannot simply subtract the dependent variable values of one data frame from the other.  I am speaking in very general terms, so I've provided a simple example.  I want to plot the residuals between two data sets that look like this:

```
data1 <- data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), y1=c(10,5,7,3,2,4))
data2 <- data.frame(x2=c(1,3,6), y2=c(1,3,2))

plot(data1, y1 ~ x1, type = 'l', lty = 1, col = 'blue', xlim = c(1,6), ylim = c(0,10))
points(data2$y2 ~ data2$x2, type = 'l', lty = 1, col = 'red')
```

So I guess my question is:

1. How can I plot the residuals of two functions (like the above) that are indexed differently.  Is there a function that will solve for the residuals between the two data sets?

EDIT1:  The example was faulty, Spacedman helped me to rectify this.

Comment: points doesn't use the formula notation, so its trying to plot data2 on the x axis and the formula 'zzzz~zz' on the y-axis and getting very confused. Try lines(data2$zz,data2$zzzz,col="red")

Comment: Thanks for the input, Spacedman, that helped me figure out how to fix the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a linear interpolation is good enough, you can use `approx` to interpolate at a bunch of X coordinates. EG:

```
> xout = sort(unique(c(seq(1,6,len=100),data1$x1,data2$x2))) # include data coords (untested)
> d1 = approx(data1$x1,data1$y1,xout)
> d2 = approx(data2$x2,data2$y2,xout)
> plot(xout,d1$y-d2$y,type="l")
```

Comment: I'd rather not use `ggplot`, as I haven't used it at all in the program I've written.  If that weren't the case, I'd definitely use this approach.  But do you know of any way to plot the residuals between the two?

Comment: That is correct.  I'll edit my post to elucidate what I'm looking for.

Comment: One thing you might also want to do is make sure the X coords of your data are included in the xout variable. I'll edit...

Comment: What exactly does that change do?

Comment: If I got it right, it makes sure that the interpolation is always evaluated at each of the x-coordinates of your data points. Otherwise your xout values will 'jump' across your data points and the interpolation won't go through your (x,y) coords. With a large len value it won't be noticable.